# Java change cursorImage with lwjgl Cursor function

Tags: java, mouse, lwjgl, illegalargumentexception

I want to change the cursor at any time of my program by giving a filename.
I call:

```
setCursor(defaultcursor);
```

The function `setCursor` looks like this:

```
private void setCursor(String image)
    {
        File file = new File("res/Cursors/"+image+".png");

        IntBuffer ib = null;
        try {
            FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
            ib = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size())
                    .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer();

            ib.rewind();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try 
        {
            org.lwjgl.input.Cursor cursor = new org.lwjgl.input.Cursor(32, 32, 0, 0, 1, ib, null);
            Mouse.setNativeCursor(cursor);
        } 
        catch (LWJGLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that all I see on my screen are a few colorful pixels. Not at all the Image I want to have.
And when I want to increase the width and height. I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 184, must be at least 1024. Because at most 1024 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 1024 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
    at org.lwjgl.input.Cursor.<init>(Cursor.java:89)
    at Entities.Player.setCursor(Player.java:86)
    at Entities.Player.checkInputs(Player.java:138)
    at Entities.Player.move(Player.java:51)
    at EngineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:82)
```

Comment: You may want to try and create an `IntBuffer` with a size of 1024 as the error suggest. (`IntBuffer buff = IntBuffer.allocate(1024).put(bufferReturnedFromFileInputStream);`). Although I haven't had any problems with it while using roughly the same method as you do. Maybe you could post this issue on the opengl forums if this doesn't help.

Comment: then i get this: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
 at java.nio.HeapIntBuffer.put(HeapIntBuffer.java:214)
 at Entities.Player.setCursor(Player.java:77)
 at Entities.Player.checkInputs(Player.java:143)
 at Entities.Player.move(Player.java:51)
 at EngineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:82)  And except for that. i do get an image. But its disorted. That is i think my main problem